Passing props to styled components in React
I have a custom styled component and I want to pass the mouse hover to it, as hover selector is not possible in 'div'.
This is what I tried:
NavLinkItem.tsx:
const NavLinkItem = styled("li")<{ mouseEnter: any }>(({ theme, mouseEnter }) => ({
    marginLeft: "7px",
    transition: "all .3s ease-in",
    color: "black",
    "&:hover": {
        color: mouseEnter ? theme.palette.primary.main : "black"
    }
}));

menuNave.tsx:
const [mouseEnter, setMouseEnter] = useState(false);

{menuItems.map((item, i) => (
    <NavLinkItem key={i} mouseEnter={mouseEnter} >
        <Link
            href={ item.path }
            onMouseEnter={() => setMouseEnter(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setMouseEnter(false)}
            style={{
                color: trigger ? "black" : "white",
                transition: "all .3s ease-in"
            }}
        >
            <Typography variant="body2">
                { item.label }
            </Typography>
        </Link>
    </NavLinkItem>
))}

But it doesn't work.
So, my question is, how can I pass the mouseEnter to my styled component?
Thanks in advance...

Don know much about styled, but maybe u need to add a useEffect to re-render the component whenever the mouseEnter param changes?

It looks like you're trying to change the color of your NavLinkItem component on hover based on a mouseEnter state. However, there are a few issues in your code that might be causing it not to work as expected.
The NavLinkItem component should directly handle the hover effect without relying on a separate mouseEnter state. Instead, you can define the hover effect directly in your styled component based on the theme palette.
You should use the "as" prop in your styled component to render it as a "div" element, as the hover effect won't work on a "li" element.
Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const NavLinkItem = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    marginLeft: "7px",
    transition: "all .3s ease-in",
    color: "black",
    "&:hover": {
        color: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
}));

// Usage
{menuItems.map((item, i) => (
    <NavLinkItem key={i}>
        <Link
            href={item.path}
            style={{
                color: trigger ? "black" : "white",
                transition: "all .3s ease-in"
            }}
        >
            <Typography variant="body2">
                {item.label}
            </Typography>
        </Link>
    </NavLinkItem>
))}


https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy
